Ubuntu 22.04 has started getting 6.8.0 kernels, which causes problem with wifi
I have on board wifi adapter as well as Tp-link archer T2u nano for dual frequency WiFi. Tp-link stopped working immediately and other onboard network WiFi too was too flacky to work with, low speed, and frequent losing connectivity.
All happened because of 6.8.0.40 kernel that installed yesterday. Is this known issue? What is the workaround?

The HWE kernel stack for Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS is the 6.8 kernel yes, and the .5 upgrades are rolling out (as expected); when you've got them all your system will report itself as 22.04.5 (instead of 22.04.4)...   The easy option is to use the GA kernel stack; ie. 5.15 is the GA kernel for the entire life of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

I've never heard that hardware support was dropped from kernels, so this should probably be reported as a bug.

I'm seeing RTL88x2bu fail as well, with rtl8822bu-dkms failing to (re)install:
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-40-generic (x86_64)  
//
installed rtl8822bu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10

